# Content area not scrolling in Phonegap, android 2.2

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

I am developing a android Phonegap app using version 1.8.1.

**I am not using JQM**, and also **do not want to use i-scroll** into this project.

I have divided my pages into three parts: (1) header, (2) content, (3) footer.

I want my header and footer remain fixed and content area scrolling (where necessary).

When I am running my app into android 4.2, everything is working fine - header & footer fixed and content area scrolls.

But if I run the application into android 2.2 ... something going wrong. Header & footer remain fixed but my content area is not scrolling.

Do you have any idea, why this difference? Is there any way (like using css3 or html5 or javascript) I can fix this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

overflow: auto; and overflow: scroll; are not supported on older android versions. Dont know about 4.2. I founded a workaround for this bug [here](http://chris-barr.com/2010/05/scrolling_a_overflowauto_element_on_a_touch_screen_device/) but it's not fluid as on iOS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But already I have finished the project in Native android.